# Load more items on grid view scroll end

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am developing a Windows Store Application in XAML/C# and I have a GridView displaying 12 items at a time (3 x 4). What I need to do is once the user scrolls to the end, more items are added to the GridView. How do I catch the event for scrolling at end?? I tried many approaches, but nothing worked...

**UPDATE:**
It took me a LOOOONG time and lots of examples to figure what I was doing wrong. ListView worked, but GridView didn't... 
Finally I noticed that the GridView items must have a width height in order for incremental loading to work.

Comment: There is a different layout tool you can use instead of gridview but can't remember what its called... Something like fluid layout

Comment: Wow... had a height and width set on a child element in my template but not on the parent element. Setting it on the outermost element fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See these examples to learn how to set `ObservableCollection<T>` that implements the `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface.

[Metro: Incrementally load GridView and ListView with ISupportIncrementalLoading](http://www.silverlightplayground.org/post/2012/06/10/Metro-Incrementally-load-GridView-and-ListView-with-ISupportIncrementalLoading.aspx)

[From the Windows 8 Camps: GridViews/ListViews and Large Data Sets](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2012/08/15/from-the-windows-8-camps-gridviews-listviews-and-large-data-sets.aspx)

[WinRT: How to properly implement ISupportIncrementalLoading with navigation](http://michelsalib.com/2012/10/21/winrt-how-to-properly-implement-isupportincrementalloading-with-navigation/)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you bind your `GridView` to a collection that implements the [ISupportIncrementalLoading interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.isupportincrementalloading%28v=win.10%29.aspx). If you do this, the `GridView` can automatically load the data when the user scrolls to the end.

For a complete example on how to do this, see Microsoft's [XAML data binding sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Data-Binding-7b1d67b5).