# Detect end of GridView / ListView in Windows Store 8.1 App

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Both GridView and ListView have a nice "bounce-effect" when you try to scroll beyond the begin or end. 
Some applications (on other platforms) use this "drag-beyond-end" gesture as a trigger for some actions, like loading more items.

How can I detect this "state" (=user is at the begin/end and tries to scroll beyond that) in Windows Store App using XAML/C# ?

Comment: You can try pull to refresh functionality using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541869/pull-to-refresh-on-windows-phone/20542854#20542854)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Now I know that it's called "pull-to-refresh"! Unfortunately the link is for WP8. I will try tough, if this concept works for store apps as well.

Comment: @tato.Rodrigo No. Didn't implement this Feature. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The rubber-band effect cannot be detected by code in a Windows 8 app (verified with the XAML controls team).

One way you could do that would be by handling all the inputs and the rubber-band effect yourself, but that is a bit of work, it reduces scrolling performance and requires manual handling of input on any list elements as well, so I would only recommend it as a last resort.

Also note the problem of the mouse input scenario since mouse scrolling doesn't involve this pull-beyond-edge behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to load more items when you reach the end of the GridView, implement the `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface with your collection derived from `ObservableCollection<T>`. See the answer here [Load more items on grid view scroll end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17238828/2342390).